# How to create alarm in SwiftUI on watchOS

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, watchos

I want to create an alarm app for my Apple Watch but I don't know how to wake a person. There is an app - Sleep Cycle and they trigger something that looks like the picture:

[image: Apple Watch with an Alarm dialog window and buttons Open and Stop]

The Watch vibrates constantly like the default timer app on Apple Watch. The question is what's the name of this interface element? This is not a notification, an Alert (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert), or a WKInterfaceDevice play function. I just want to reproduce that behaviour. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `notifyUserWithHaptic`, it gives a repeating haptic and also displays this notification style screen with Open and Stop buttons if the app isn't active.

As per Apple Docs

> For schedulable sessions such as smart alarms, call this method during
> the session to alert the user. When you call the method, the system
> plays repeating haptic feedback. If the app isn’t active, the system
> also displays a system alarm alert on the watch.

[Link to Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextendedruntimesession/3333286-notifyuserwithhaptic?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks, it works